# SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: php, database, laravel

I logged in to my heroku app which is a hotel review app: http://immense-beach-76879.herokuapp.com/. Apparently, it won't display the data I entered at http://immense-beach-76879.herokuapp.com/reviews. It was only showing the error. It said something about the integer being the wrong choice to use since "kiki" is supposed to be a string, correct? If you need to look at my code, here it is: https://github.com/kikidesignnet/hotelreviews.

Here is my error:

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "kiki" (SQL: select * from "reviews" where "user_id" in (1, kiki, k@k.com, ?, 2020-02-07 05:57:47, 2020-02-07 05:57:47) order by "created_at" desc limit 20)
```

I've been following this tutorial to learn about Laravel and how React/Laravel works together: https://kaloraat.com/articles/laravel-react-crud-tutorial and their github repo:https://github.com/kaloraat/laravel-react-crud

Here is my migrating `create_reviews_table.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateReviewsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('reviews');
    }
}
```

As you can see, this app was supposed to register a new user. Then when the user log in and submit a review of the hotel, the reviews.api was supposed to save the data in and display the reviews underneath the review form.

All I can see is that the form is working, submitting the data underneath but it's not showing any dada...

Comment: That `SELECT` query looks obviously wrong, but your code does not contain any fragments that build that query. Please share the proper parts of your code, and your debugging attempts

Comment: plz post the line that this error point to

Comment: Here is my github repo: https://github.com/kikidesignnet/hotelreviews

Comment: @TsaiKoga how? I don't know what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change this line (17) in your `index` method inside `App\Http\Controllers\ReviewController`

```
$allReviews = $review->whereIn('user_id', $request->user())->with('user');
```

To

```
$allReviews = $review->where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->with('user');
```

Or

```
$allReviews = $review->where('user_id', \Auth::id())->with('user');
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Was it `whereIn` that's causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, `WhereIn` method accept array in its 2nd argument however $request->user() return an object (current authenticated user).